# Last member of a list is a memory position

Tags: prolog

I don't understand why with this predicate the last position is a memory position.

```
elimina_diretos(_,[],_).
elimina_diretos(LA,[H|T],LP):-
    member(H,LA),
    elimina_diretos(LA,T,LP).
elimina_diretos(LA,[H|T],[H|LP]):-
    elimina_diretos(LA,T,LP).
```

If I type

```
?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],L).
```

Prolog gives me:

```
L = [pedro, rocha|_G609] ;
```

how can I clean that `_G609`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change:

```
elimina_diretos(_,[],[]).
```

Note that your code must be made deterministic, or you'll get unwanted 'solutions' on backtracking:

```
?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],L).
L = [pedro, rocha] ;
L = [pedro, rocha, andre] ;
...
```

Then the second change (note the cut):

```
elimina_diretos(LA,[H|T],LP):-
    memberchk(H,LA),!,
    elimina_diretos(LA,T,LP).
```

Now should work as you expect

```
?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],L).
L = [pedro, rocha] ;
false.
```

Use [`memberchk/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2) instead of `member/2`, it's far more efficient.

Comment: @false: I find your comment misleading. Do you really expect a newbie could appreciate the unpleasant problems about abstract Prolog model ?

Comment: You are suggesting to a newbie a highly procedural, non-logical built-in that is quite difficult to use correctly. In fact, your program does not work for many modes which makes understanding Prolog's idea one step more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your program. But first, `_G609` is just a logical variable. You are right to assume that this number is somewhat related to the concrete memory location. This idiosyncratic way of indicating a variable at the toplevel <del>is</del> was specific to SWI-Prolog. Other system produce a more comprehensive result, for example GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],L).
L = [pedro,rocha|_] ? ;
```

More commonly, `_A` is used.

So this answer means that `L` is a partial list that **starts** with `pedro` and `rocha`. Is this what you intended? It means that also

```
?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],[pedro,rocha,jose]).
   true
; false.
```

Is this really what you intended? I think not. But since you did not state what the relation should describe, it is difficult to guess.

This is not the only problem with your program. We only looked at the first answer but let us look also at the subsequent answers!

```
?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],L).
   L = [pedro,rocha|_A]
;  L = [pedro,rocha,andre|_A]
;  L = [pedro,tiago,rocha|_A]
;  L = [pedro,tiago,rocha,andre|_A].
```

So there are more answers!

Here is a very general method to find such errors rapidly. When testing, start with the most general query and look the answer in detail:

```
?- elimina_diretos(A, B, C).
   B = []
;  A = [_A|_B], B = [_A]
;  ... .
```

That means: `elimina_diretos/3` is true **for all** `A` and `C` with `B = []`. I very much doubt that this is what you wanted to describe.

---

((since everybody just posts answers, I have to follow suit))

```
elimina_diretos(_,[],[]).
elimina_diretos(LA,[H|T],LP):-
    member(H,LA),
    elimina_diretos(LA,T,LP).
elimina_diretos(LA,[H|T],[H|LP]):-
    maplist(dif(H),LA),
    elimina_diretos(LA,T,LP).
```

This solution does not depend on (unspecified) modes. Both @mbratch's and @CapelliC's solution do depend (somehow) and fail incorrectly for:

```
?- elimina_diretos([X], [pedro,tiago],[pedro]).
   X = tiago
;  false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw another option into the ring of a couple of good answers.

As CapelliC has already indicated, one issue is that the base case isn't quite correct: `elimina_diretos(_, [], _).` This says that removing any set of items from an empty list, I get an anonymous variable. The right "answer" in this case would be the empty list: `elimina_diretos(_, [], []).`

With that as the only change, you then get good answers with the multiple solution issue that CapelliC mentioned.

Another option for reworking the clauses would be as follows:

```
elimina_diretos([], L, L).             % Remove nothing from L is L
elimina_diretos([H|T], L, LP):-
    (   delete(H, L, L1)             % L1 is L with all H's removed
    ->  elimina_diretos(T, L1, LP)
    ;   elimina_diretos(T, L, LP)    % There are no H's in L
    ).
```

Which produces:

```
| ?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],L).

L = [pedro,rocha] ? ;

no

| ?- elimina_diretos([a,b,c], [a,c,e,f], L).

L = [e,f]

yes

| ?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],[pedro,rocha,jose]).

no

| ?- elimina_diretos([tiago,andre],[pedro,tiago,rocha,andre],[pedro,rocha,andre]).

no
```